# angular-drag-and-drop-lists - Auto scroll not working while dragging item in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, autoscroll, angulardraganddroplists

I'm using angular-drag-and-drop-lists,
I have some list of items. I want to drag and drop item from 'position A' to 'position B'. The 'position B' is at bottom of the page. **Need to scroll the IE browser.** **But it is not scrolling when dragging is started.** In chrome, it is working fine. What can I do?

[Please check this IE browser](https://embed.plnkr.co/pWuqhX/)

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce your problem on my side (using IE 11.17134.1.0), based on your code, I create a sample on my side, the result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cruN2.gif).

<s>Please check your IE browser version, and try to [use F12 developer tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/bg182326(v=vs.85)) to check whether it contain some error. Besides, you could also try to upgrade the IE browser version.</s>

I also test the code on IE 10, it still works well. So, please try to [use F12 developer tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/bg182326(v=vs.85)) to check whether it contain some error.